# Get first number in a line using grep

Tags: bash, grep

Example File text.txt:

13 25 hello

I'm trying to use grep to get the first number in a file with only 1 line, and the number could be of any length, in this example my expected output is 13.

I've tried this regex (\d+), which in a regex editor like regexr gives me the correct output, but grep does not produce any output.

```
grep -o '(\d+)' test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like:

```
grep -oE '^\s*[0-9]+' text.file
```

or

```
sed 's/[ \t]*\([0-9]\{1,\}\).*/\1/' text.file
```

Example:

```
echo "13 25 hello" > text.txt
grep -oE '^\s*[0-9]+' text.file
Output: 13
sed 's/[ \t]*\([0-9]\{1,\}\).*/\1/' text.file 
Output: 13
```

--

```
echo "9912 25 hello" > text.txt
grep -oE '^\s*[0-9]+' text.file
Output: 9912
sed 's/[ \t]*\([0-9]\{1,\}\).*/\1/' text.file 
Output: 9912
```